# get the position of same 3 charecter in string if exists using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, string, sql-server-2008-r2

i have 3 charecters common in string like that

```
 ABCxcdk893         --yes 
 xxxABCpoe4
 ABCkkksdlk         --yes
 ABC4899kff         --yes
 er45346gdf
```

now how to iterate through each charecter of all string and get the matched string with pattern like in our case

```
  %[_ABC_]%[0,7]
```

WHAT I DID ?

```
       while @i < @len
  begin
set @char = SUBSTRING(@MyString, @i,1)

if @char not like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
begin

      ?????--HERE ITERATION
  --  set @char = ''

end
 else
    begin

   --PATTERN MAKING?????????

  -- set @i = @i + 1
  end
--set @result =???????
 set @i = @i + 1
 end
```

You will not understand that and  I  know that thing so you can provide me the code that matches 2 3 strings and return same 3 charecter at same place if exxist  I  mean the same pattern exists in 3 strings.

Comment: ALL CAPS is equivalent to shouting in online forums.  And shouting is unnecessary.  You need to explain your problem, starting with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Since you are using sql server, the patindex function is worth looking into.

Comment: this may be ABC at start or any other where and i also donot now its is ABC at begining or _http:/_  but i want the patheren of three strings

Comment: It looks like [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I'm confused.  You say you want to match the same pattern and see if it exists in 3 strings, yet in your example above the only pattern that matches in your 3 strings is `ABC`.  Please clarify.  Do you only need to see if `ABC` is present at the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you clearly, you want to get all pairs of strings with matching 3 letter patterns located at the same position.
Here is a little snippet for you.

I'am assuming that you have a table with strings.

```sql
DECLARE @strs TABLE (s varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @strs (s) VALUES ('ABCxcdk893'), ('xxxABCpoe4'), ('ABCkkksdlk'), ('ABC4899kff'), ('er45346gdf')
```

The trick is to

1. make all 3 letter patterns from all strings
2. compare strings with patterns

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE (n int)
DECLARE @n int = (SELECT MAX(LEN(s) - 2) FROM @strs)

WHILE @n > 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @t (n) VALUES (@n)
    SET @n = @n - 1
END

SELECT s.s, p.s, p.pat 
FROM @strs s 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT s, n, SUBSTRING(s, n, 3) AS pat 
            FROM @strs CROSS JOIN @t
            WHERE n <= LEN(s) - 2 
        ) p ON s.s <> p.s
WHERE CHARINDEX(p.pat, s.s) = p.n
```

Comment: nice answer, provided thats what the OP is asking.  Who knows! :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first attempt at solving your issues, since I'm still not exactly clear on what you want...

```
SELECT *
FROM [data table]
WHERE [field name] LIKE 'ABC%'
       OR [field name] LIKE 'http://ABC%'
```

This will match any string that begins with `ABC` or begins with `http://ABC`.  Please provide some more examples if you need something different than this.